# Font suddenly is unreadable

Tags: 20.04, fonts

Running ubuntu 20.04 suddenly all the desktop font and menus will look like this [image] This seems to happen at least once a day. not quite sure what to do other than restart.

Answer (score 1):

I've been experiencing similar behavior rarely. I'm not aware of the cause yet, but this will at least provide a work-around.

Do `ALT` + `F2` to open an interface where you can run commands.

> Pop up command window (for quickly running commands).
> - https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-keyboard-shortcuts.html.en

Execute `r`, which will restart [GNOME Shell](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell).

> **Typing 'r' or 'restart' in the Alt+F2 prompt** will restart GNOME Shell.
> - https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/CheatSheet

After a few seconds, everything should return to normal.

Comment: thanks. this is a good stop gap I guess. it would be nice to not have to randomly do this like twice a day though.